# Response headers update with declarativeNetRequest update rules not visible in Chrome's DevTools

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-declarativenetrequest

In my chrome extension V3 I use `chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateSessionRules` to modify response headers:

```
chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateSessionRules({
    addRules: [
    {
      id: 999,
      priority: 1,
      condition: {
        initiatorDomains: ['localhost'],
        resourceTypes: ['main_frame']
      },
      action: {
         type: 'modifyHeaders',
         responseHeaders: [
            { header: 'Content-Security-Policy', operation: 'remove' },
            { header: "bar-foo-baz", operation: "set", value: "true" },
        ],
     } 
   }]
});
```

The test I do is pretty simple. I violate the `Content-Security-Policy` rule so I get an error in the console. But when I apply the `remove` operation all works fine and the error is gone.

But the weird thing is if I look in the DevTools Network tab, I still see the Content-Security-Policy header and I don't see `bar-foo-baz`.

[image]

Does someone know why this is happening?

Comment: https://crbug.com/1247400

Comment: wow this bug has been there for 2 years now 

Comment: @wOxxOm is this "visual" bug or the headers are actually not modified?